# Async FIFO master / slave

Tags: digital-logic, interface, ftdi, fifo

Consider an asynchronous FIFO interface (e.g. FT245, FT2232H or comparable). Since there is no clock, how do you decide who deserved to be called master? Or do you call it controller instead?

Comment: Having a clock or not having a clock is nothing to do with a device being master or slave. The FT245 (as far as I know) extracts clock from the USB data it receives and generates this clock internally.

Comment: In syncronous mode you are certainly right, but I'm talking about async. Here our control signals are called RXF, TXE, RD, WR. This is why I wonder

Comment: @Andyaka - The FT245 (and the FT232, actually) have internal oscillators for their USB interface.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: Probably right again, but not my question :) Guys -- anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of the devices you referenced, but in a general async FIFO there is a "pushing" side and a "popping" side.

The side which pushes into the FIFO is usually called master, and the side that pops from it is a target.

I don't understand why do you have difficulties in identifying the master without clock - the side which initiates the transaction is a master. I hope I didn't misunderstand your question...

Comment: I was mainly asking for nomenclature. I think in the future I will use pushing and popping side, since it's descriptive

Answer (score 0):

In a typical asynchronous FIFO design, both sides of the FIFO can act as slaves to the external device connecting them.  It may be necessary for either side to wait for the other, but such waiting need not be "precise".  If the device that wants to fetch data polls the FIFO and finds that none is available, it need not poll again until it's possible that the FIFO might be nearly full.  Conversely, if the device that wants to put data into the FIFO finds it full, even if it's imperative that the FIFO never go completely empty, it need not poll again until it's possible that the FIFO might be nearly empty.

Note that when using a "true" asynchronous FIFO, if one only has an indicator that "at least one byte is available for reading" [as opposed to something indicating a larger quantity], the reading side will need to have some sort of clock that/s at least 2x/3x the fastest desired reading speed.  This clock need not feed the FIFO, but rather the master, which must in separate steps determine whether data is available and then request it.  If the FIFO can indicate when multiple bytes of data are available, the master may be able to request all those bytes on consecutive clock cycles without having to check availability between them.  Similar issues exist on the transmit side of the FIFO.

A nicer design is to have each side of the FIFO be a synchronous subsystem with its own clock.  This sort of design makes it possible to have the interface between each side of the FIFO and its master include data wires along with a signal saying whether the data should be considered valid, and then output a signal saying whether the data was accepted.  A side that has data to send can put it on its data wires and indicate that it's valid, and then continue to do so until it gets an indication that the data wire was accepted, which will then enable it to make new data available on the following cycle.  When the FIFO gets full or runs dry, a synchronization delay will be required before data transfer can resume, but as long as it is either full nor empty data may be processed continuously.  Note that at least one rather nice way of designing such a system may be covered by Xilinx's patents (I don't know the details of those patents) but there are some other possible designs which--though less elegant--should be unencumbered.